# case class generics with play json

Tags: playframework

I am reading https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaJsonGenerics

The  `SearchResult[T]` example is exactly what I want,but I have compiling error with it：

import play.api.libs.json._

```
case class SearchResults[T](
                             elements: List[T],
                             page: Int,
                             pageSize: Int,
                             total :Int
                           )
object SearchResults
{
  implicit def searchResultsReads[T](implicit fmt: Reads[T]): Reads[SearchResults[T]] = new Reads[SearchResults[T]] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): SearchResults[T] = new SearchResults[T] (

      (json \ "elements") match {
        case JsArray(ts) => ts.map(t => Json.fromJson(t)(fmt))
        case _ => throw new RuntimeException("Elements MUST be a list")
      },
      (json \ "page").as[Int],
      (json \ "pageSize").as[Int],
      (json \ "total").as[Int]
    )
  }

  implicit def searchResultsWrites[T](implicit fmt: Writes[T]): Writes[SearchResults[T]] = new Writes[SearchResults[T]] {
    def writes(ts: SearchResults[T]) = JsObject(Seq(
      "page" -> JsNumber(ts.page),
      "pageSize" -> JsNumber(ts.pageSize),
      "total" -> JsNumber(ts.total),
      "elements" -> JsArray(ts.elements.map(Json.toJson(_)))
    ))
  }
}
```

I have the following compiling error:

```
Error:(17, 14) constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : play.api.libs.json.JsArray
 required: play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult
        case JsArray(ts) => ts.map(t => Json.fromJson(t)(fmt))
```

Comment: Please share the actual compile error message, and your `SearchResults` case class.

Comment: Thanks @zoltán, I update my question, please help take a look at it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The methods `fromJson` and `toJson` are the ones defined in class:

```
play.api.libs.json.Json
```

Comment: Thanks you @luca-t, by using the `Json` ojbect, I have other compiling errors, please help take a look, thank you.